# python AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'display'

Tags: python, pygame

I'm starting to use Python specifically the module pygame, but when i try to create a window this error occurs

```
>>> import pygame
>>> (width, height) = (300, 200)
>>> screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'display'
```

Help me please.

Comment: you might need to call `pygame.init()` first

Comment: Make sure you didn't call your own files or folders `pygame.py` or `pygame`.

Comment: You must have accidentally over-shadowed pygame in your interpreter, or locally in your project must have something named pygame. That call works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I think it's either what njzk2 suggested, or it's possible that you're using a version of pygame that doesn't have that attribute. You can find out by calling `dir(pygame)` and see what attributes it has. What version of pygame are you using?

Comment: I did not have to call `init` to get it working. Something else is wrong. I still suspect over-shadowing.

Answer (score 2):

You probably are overshadowing pygame library with any other file with same name such as pygame.py which may be in the same file

If you are using windows, just search for pygame.py in the search box in start menu. Right click the result and click "open file location". Just delete the pyagame.py file from the folder.
Or you can print the path of the offending module by :

```
    import pygame
    print('Path to module:',pygame._file_)
```

Comment: copy pasting the above code didn't work for me, maybe because pygame._file_ has only one underscore it should be:
 `print('Path to module:',pygame.__file__)`